# Default Instance Missing

Tags: sql-server

I am migrating a server that has SQL Server installed - current server Windows 2012 with SQL Server 2012 and target server windows 2019 with SQL Server 2019.  Obviously I am trying to mirror the configuration in current server to ensure as few a changes as possible.  In the current server, checking the SQL Server Configuration Manager and checking the registry both visually and using script below there does not appear to be a default "MSSQLSERVER" instance setup.

```
DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE
( Value nvarchar(100),
InstanceNames nvarchar(100),
Data nvarchar(100))

Insert into @GetInstances
EXECUTE xp_regread
@rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
@key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',
@value_name = 'InstalledInstances'

Select InstanceNames from @GetInstances
```

However, in the current server I can login to SSMS with SA credentials WITHOUT stipulating an instance - that is just using the database engine name and not database engine name\instance, which, unless I am wrong,  usually means it connects to the default MSSQLSERVER instance.

Does this mean there IS a default instance setup on current server somewhere?  If so how would I find it?

Comment: Are you specifying the port instead?

Comment: @Larnu No, I am not specifying a port number no.  Also, on current server in SSMS, before clicking on connect button if I click on Options it states in "connect to database" the value <default>.  I was under the impression if there was no default instance then to connect, the user HAD to specify an instance.  If no instance was specified and there IS a default instance it connects to the default

Comment: The <default> in "Connect to database" has nothing to do with the SQL Server instance name, it means to use the `DEFAULT_DATABASE` setting configured for the account being logged in via [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql#default_database-database) or [ALTER LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks - this is all good info.  So, can you say why it "appears" to log into a default MSSQLSERVER instance?  Could it be a database file somewhere else in C drive?